# Login in screen pops up in sourcetree

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

My desktop was previously used by the previous employee at my office. In `source tree` I have my account logged in but my at random times the previous users login screen pops up with username field disabled

[image]

[image]

and it comes two times,when I click cancel the second screen pops up. I am fed up with this problem. I have done with everything to try and solve this problem but it will just not go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quite often this occurs because either a repo has multiple remotes, or a repo has a remote that you've not got permissions to anymore is still bookmarked (even if the tab isn't open in SourceTree).

For example I had 3 repos from a previous contract that I no longer had access too, whilst I didn't have the repos open in tabs within SourceTree, the repo was bookmarked so SourceTree kept trying to authenticate it; removing the bookmarks and then restarting SourceTree fixed the problem.

**Removing old/non accessible repositories**

[image: local repositories]

1. In the latest version of Source Tree (2.1.2.5 at the time of writing), Select the New Tab + button, under Local repositories -> All Repos ensure that all the Repos are ones you have access to (might have to check each one can do a fetch)
2. Delete any bookmarks you do not need/have access to
3. Restart Source Tree

**Removing old/duplicate/excessive remotes**

[image: Repository Settings]

1. Select your repository tab
2. Go to the Repository menu and select Repository settings (Ctrl+Shift+,)
3. Under the "Remotes" table, ensure the remotes are correct (most likely just origin pointing to bitbucket)

Good luck.

Comment: +1 It would still be nice if SourceTree was mentioning for which repo it cannot authenticate itself, so we would not need to check all our repos.

Comment: I can fetch the repo. There is only one remote and yet I see this login popup.

Comment: This issue was driving me crazy, and this answer solved it for me.  Thank you!

Comment: I have dozens of repos, fortunately it was the last one I added which was in this situation.